# Workaround for a large Worksheet_Change procedure for 32-Bit Excel 2010?

Tags: vba, excel, 32bit-64bit, worksheet

I have a spreadsheet that serves a data entry where I have standardized and validated the data being entered into each cell of interest on the spreadsheet. The data validation/standardization was done using the `Worksheet_Change` event. I have opted to use VBA instead of the Excel built-in data validation because the latter only works if you type in value, copying and pasting from another spreadsheet will overwrite any data validation.

Given the number of data fields (cells) that need to be validated, the `Worksheet_Change` sub has grown very large. This was no problem for 64-bit Excel, however 32-bit Excel chokes with `Procedure too large` error. The only way is to break down the procedure, but that is not possible given the nature of the procedure (change event). Any help would be great.

Edit: I have included a snippet to show the structure of the `Worksheet_Change` sub

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cell   As Range
    Set cell = Range("Range1")
    If Not Application.Intersect(cell, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
       'Run Validation for Range1
    End If
    Set cell = Range("Range2")
    If Not Application.Intersect(cell, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
       'Run Validation for Range2
    End If
    ....
End Sub
```

Thanks,

Comment: Do you have everything in the _Change event? Or are you calling subs from the _change event?

Comment: How much goes on between End If and End Sub?  ...

Comment: A lot over 1000 lines of code, I have close to 100 named ranges.

Comment: How many of them are shared?  As in, do you have 100 different types of validation? I think you need to identify how many unique validation types you are using.  Then have a sub for each specific type accepting incoming arguments from the _change event. ie, SSN, date, phone, numbers only, alpha only, etc.  
Don't repeat yourself.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing how the part of code for validation looks like i could thing of something like the following. You write separated methods for each validation type, and so the code should not exceed it's allowed length.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    WorksheetChanged Target
End Sub

Private Sub WorksheetChanged(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim names As Variant
    Dim name As Variant
    Dim namedRange As Range

    names = Array("Range1", "Range2", "Range3") ' etc. until all your 100 named ranges

    For Each name In names
        Set namedRange = Range(name)
        If Not Application.Intersect(namedRange, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
           Validate Target, namedRange
           Exit For
        End If
    Next name
End Sub

Private Sub Validate(ByVal Target As Range, ByVal namedRange As Range)
    Select Case namedRange.name.name
        Case "Range1", "Range2"
            ' Run Validation for Range1,2
            Validate1 Target
        Case "Range3"
            ' Run Validation for Range3
            Validate2 Target
        Case Else
            Err.Raise 123, "This name is not supported for validation"
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub Validate1(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' Specific validation here
End Sub

Private Sub Validate2(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' Specific validation here
End Sub
```